# Create docker image that depends on two items

Tags: docker, .net-core, wine

I need to create a docker image for my app.
my app will need:

- .net core
- wine installation

How to achieve that?
Should I use a certain linux distribution as base image, and install package for those 2 dependencies (I am not sure how to add installation package).

or
should I just use .net core base image,
and use portable wine (if they exist) (so I can just copy the files in Dockerfile)?

Thanks

Comment: I would use the .net core base image and install wine on it.

Comment: Can you run these two on separate container images?